# How to generate a hashed share link using flask

Tags: hash, hyperlink, flask

I am developing an app, and I want to realize the "share" function, which can share the content to facebook or twitter. Every content has its own id, and I want to generate a hashed link when the "share" button is clicked. Say, if there is an essay A, and I want to share it to facebook, so I click the "share to facebook" button. Then it should generate a url, which looks like "http//my_app_backstage_server/essay/hash(id)", where hash(id) is not the real id of the content, but the hashed one. How can I implement this in Flask framework?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebook like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [twitter](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet) just create link to your page on facebook (if you don't want generate special links for this actions). So you need just provide content pages access.

You can generate random string or real hash and store it on database (don't forget that this value must be unique):

```
import random
import string
from hashlib import sha512

SIMPLE_CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def get_random_string(length=24):
    return ''.join(random.choice(SIMPLE_CHARS) for i in xrange(length))

def get_random_hash(length=24):
    hash = sha512()
    hash.update(get_random_string())
    return hash.hexdigest()[:length]
```

I think you don't need have both id and hash access for content.

If you want generate links for any share button action (I realy can't understand why):

1. you must add route for this links;
2. you must add route to create link;
3. you can create link by ajax and share it after if you don't have user permission to share data;
4. you can create link by app (ajax or just link) if you have user permission to share data.